# Enable the writing of ANSI escape codes on a file?

Tags: c++, c++17, ansi-escape

I am struggling with a problem. I searched all around the web and StackOverflow website and found similar questions, but none of them provided me the answer I am searching.

I am on a Linux system (Ubuntu) and basically want to know how to write an ANSI escape code in an output file. For example, if I want to write a red string on the terminal I do:

```
cout << "\033[31m" << "Red string";
```

and it works. But if I want to write it on a .rtf file for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ofstream os( "this_file.rtf" );
os << "\033[31m" << "Red string";
os.close();
```

it doesn't work and output in the file something like:

```
#[31mRed string
```

is there a way to enable the writing of an ANSI escape code on an output file like that one? Thanks.

Comment: Did you compare the files? I guess the difference is just the filename and the program that interprets the files' contents. Displaying something as RTF is simply something different than displaying it as e.g. ASCII or HTML. BTW: You've done a bad job picking the tags for your question, neither "linux" nor "fileoutputstream" apply, which should be obvious for anyone reading the description.

Comment: Did you try `cat this_file.rtf`? You need to view the contents with something that is aware of escape codes.

Comment: RTF (Rich Text Format) doesn't use ANSI escape codes for formatting.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sorry for tags, I seen you corrected them, thanks. However I tried this with many other kind of files (.odt, .rtf etc) and the problem persists. Is there a way to write a colored string for example in one of these files?

Comment: @GianlucaBianco Every file format uses a different syntax to implement coloring of the interpreted text. You need to follow the specification of the file format, not use escape codes.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, with cat it works. Therefore I am wondering if it would be possible to write a colored string on such a file. Do you know what are the file extensions supporting these sequences?

Comment: @user17732522 thanks. Didn't know about this.

Comment: There is no universal method for indicating text colour. The ANSI escape codes only matter to certain terminals.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco The only case where escape codes make sense is plain text files and probably only if read in a terminal. But even then it is likely that the program reading the file will not pass through the escape codes to the terminal in order to prevent messing up the presentation or to avoid malicious escape sequences. For example `less` has the `-R` and `-r` options to enable this (partially).

Comment: RTF uses a color table defined in the head, thus appending with a new color is doubtful as approach. I strongly recommend that you get yourself a library specific for RTF, if you want to write files in that format, or consider a different format, depending on what you need. Other formats might be more straight forward when it comes to local formating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all your answers and weeks of practice, the solution for this answer is pretty obvious and is the following: file redirection of ANSI escape sequences manipulation depends on the kind of file you are writing in and you have to manually set the way in which you want to translate the ANSI into the output file, depending of course also on the file format you are considering.